# Save an item at the MapCanvas

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer, save, mapcanvas

I am using PyQGIS to generate some polylines.
The lines are shown at the MapCanvas.
How do I save these lines to a vector layer?

My PyQGIS :

```
class LængdeBreddeGrader :

  from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateTransform

  def __init__(self, x1, x2, y1, y2 ) :
    self.iface = iface
    self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    canvasCrs = self.canvas.mapSettings().destinationCrs()
    WGS84 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform( WGS84, canvasCrs, QgsProject.instance() )
    self.linje = QgsFeature()
    for x in range( x1 , x2+1 ) :
      punkter = []
      for y5 in range( 5*y1, 5*y2+1 ) :
        punkt = tr.transform( QgsPointXY( x, y5/5 ) )
        punkter.append( QgsPoint(punkt) )
      self.TegnLinje( punkter )
    for y in range( y1, y2+1 ) :
      punkter = []
      for x5 in range( 5*x1, 5*x2+1 ) :
        punkt = tr.transform( QgsPointXY( x5/5, y ) )
        punkter.append( QgsPoint(punkt) )
      self.TegnLinje( punkter )

  def TegnLinje(self, punkter ) :
    self.linje = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, False)
    self.linje.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(punkter), None)
    self.linje.setColor(QColor( 0, 0, 0 ))
    self.linje.setWidth( 1 )
```

Comment: Can you please attach some code to your question ? Otherwise, it may be closed

Answer (score 4):

Construct a new layer within `__init__` method.

```
self.new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={canvasCrs.authid()}",
                                "New Layer",
                                "memory")
```

And change `TegnLinje` method to this:

```
def TegnLinje(self, punkter) :
    feature = QgsFeature()
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(punkter))
    self.new_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
```

The whole script:

```
class LangdeBreddeGrader:

    from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateTransform

    def __init__(self, x1, x2, y1, y2):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        canvasCrs = self.canvas.mapSettings().destinationCrs()

        self.new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(
            f"LineString?crs={canvasCrs.authid()}", "New Layer", "memory")

        WGS84 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
        tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(WGS84, canvasCrs, QgsProject.instance())

        for x in range(x1, x2+1):
            punkter = []
            for y5 in range(5*y1, 5*y2+1):
                punkt = tr.transform(QgsPointXY(x, y5/5))
                punkter.append(QgsPoint(punkt))
            self.TegnLinje(punkter)
        for y in range(y1, y2+1):
            punkter = []
            for x5 in range(5*x1, 5*x2+1):
                punkt = tr.transform(QgsPointXY(x5/5, y))
                punkter.append(QgsPoint(punkt))
            self.TegnLinje(punkter)

        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.new_layer)

    def TegnLinje(self, punkter):
        feature = QgsFeature()
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(punkter))
        self.new_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
```

Usage:

```
LangdeBreddeGrader(26, 45, 36, 42)
```

Result:

[image]

---

Actually, you don't need to construct a class. Instead, you can use a function as follows:

```
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateTransform

def make_grid(x1, x2, y1, y2):

    def add_to_layer(punkter):
        feature = QgsFeature()
        feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(punkter))
        new_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])

    crs = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs()

    new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(
        f"LineString?crs={crs.authid()}", "New Layer", "memory")

    WGS84 = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(WGS84, crs, QgsProject.instance())

    for x in range(x1, x2+1):
        punkter = []
        for y5 in range(5*y1, 5*y2+1):
            punkt = tr.transform(QgsPointXY(x, y5/5))
            punkter.append(QgsPoint(punkt))
        add_to_layer(punkter)
    for y in range(y1, y2+1):
        punkter = []
        for x5 in range(5*x1, 5*x2+1):
            punkt = tr.transform(QgsPointXY(x5/5, y))
            punkter.append(QgsPoint(punkt))
        add_to_layer(punkter)

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)


make_grid(26, 45, 36, 42)
```